# Unity3d 5.6.3p2 error CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

installed on the new Windows 10 version of Unity 5.6.3p2, then last Google SDK and Java 1.8 and tried to compile its project collected earlier on the same version, as a result issued the following error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
```

> C:\Users\Maksim\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.1\aapt.exe
>   package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml"
>   -S "res" -I "C:/Users/Maksim/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar"
>   -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.google.android.gms.ads.impl:com.google.android.gms.ads:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.clearcut:com.google.android.gms.gass:com.google.android.gms.tasks:android.support.v4
>   -S "C:\Users\Maksim\Desktop\UnityProjects\S\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-10.2.4\res"
>   -S "C:\Users\Maksim\Desktop\UnityProjects\S\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-10.2.4\res"
>   -S "C:\Users\Maksim\Desktop\UnityProjects\S\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.4\res"
>   -S "C:\Users\Maksim\Desktop\UnityProjects\S\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-10.2.4\res"
>   -S "C:\Users\Maksim\Desktop\UnityProjects\S\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-clearcut-10.2.4\res"
>   -S "C:\Users\Maksim\Desktop\UnityProjects\S\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-gass-10.2.4\res"
>   -S "C:\Users\Maksim\Desktop\UnityProjects\S\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-tasks-10.2.4\res"
>   -S "C:\Users\Maksim\Desktop\UnityProjects\S\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-24.0.0\res"

I've already tried to solve it in many ways that I found, for example, replacing the contents of the folder tools in Android SDK or deleting duplicate files .aar but this did not help. Also in some of the boards I found that it is necessary to perform some manipulations in the Plugins/android folder in the project, but I do not have the android folder in the project in the way Plugins.
What can be done?

Comment: Have you been able to fix this ? If yes, please share the solution as I am having the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, the problem was in the compiled project itself, that is, I removed the third-party plug-in from the project and eventually found the one that caused the error, and also the installation of older versions of Google SDK and Java could help and also reinstall individual components in Google SDK.

Comment: That is great.  I can try those steps. Thanks.